# Question about replacing character in text file

Tags: text-processing, sed

So I have some data that is parsed in this format seperated by colons:

```
username:email@email.com:password:salt
```

Sometimes the username/salt can contain a colon (:) in it.
I want to replace the separators with a different character so the data would be like this:

```
username', 'email@email.com', 'password', 'salt
```

I was using this command:

```
sed "s/:/'/" filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

But I can't think of a way to skip the colons in the username/salt fields.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Content of file:

```
username:email@email.com:password:salt
user:name:email@email.com:password:salt
username:email@email.com:password:sa:lt
user:name:email@email.com:password:sa:lt
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E "s/(.*):([^:]*@[^:]*):([^:]*):(.*)/\1', '\2', '\3', '\4/" file
```

Output:

```
username', 'email@email.com', 'password', 'salt
user:name', 'email@email.com', 'password', 'salt
username', 'email@email.com', 'password', 'sa:lt
user:name', 'email@email.com', 'password', 'sa:lt
```